# Unexpected token FROM controller

Tags: controller, custom-controller

I have the following controller and I am getting this error: Unexpected token FROM on line 7 and 18. Can anyone help me to fix this.

```
public with sharing class TestMyPropertyController {
@AuraEnabled
public static List<pba__Listing__c> getSimilarProperties (Id recordId, String searchCriteria, Decimal beds, Decimal price, Decimal priceRange ) {
     if (searchCriteria == 'Bedrooms') {
         return [
             SELECT Id, Name, pba__Bedrooms_pb__c, pba__FullBathrooms_pb__c, pba__ListingPrice_pb__c, PropertyOwnerContact__c, pba__Status__c, 
             FROM pba__Listing__c WHERE Id != :recordId AND pba__Bedrooms_pb__c = :beds
         ];
     } else {
         Decimal range;
         if (priceRange == null) {
             range = 100000;
         } else {
             range = priceRange;
         }
         return [
             SELECT Id, Name, pba__Bedrooms_pb__c, pba__FullBathrooms_pb__c, pba__ListingPrice_pb__c, PropertyOwnerContact__c, pba__Status__c, 
             FROM pba__Listing__c WHERE Id != :recordId AND pba__ListingPrice_pb__c > :price - range AND pba__ListingPrice_pb__c < :price + range
         ];
     }
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you run your queries individually in dev console or workbench to see if they dont have any issues?

Comment: Hello no I haven't run queries individually in dev console or workbench

Comment: Please do so, I have a feeling that there's something fishy in your soql. Specially, `pba__ListingPrice_pb__c > :price - range`.

Comment: You should then, that's how you debug!

Answer (score 2):

You have `,` before **`From`** in soql, remove that and it should work (line 7,line 17)

```
public with sharing class TestMyPropertyController {
@AuraEnabled
public static List<pba__Listing__c> getSimilarProperties (Id recordId, String searchCriteria, Decimal beds, Decimal price, Decimal priceRange ) {
     if (searchCriteria == 'Bedrooms') {
         return [
             SELECT Id, Name, pba__Bedrooms_pb__c, pba__FullBathrooms_pb__c, pba__ListingPrice_pb__c, PropertyOwnerContact__c, pba__Status__c 
             FROM pba__Listing__c WHERE Id != :recordId AND pba__Bedrooms_pb__c = :beds
         ];
     } else {
         Decimal range;
         if (priceRange == null) {
             range = 100000;
         } else {
             range = priceRange;
         }
         return [
             SELECT Id, Name, pba__Bedrooms_pb__c, pba__FullBathrooms_pb__c, pba__ListingPrice_pb__c, PropertyOwnerContact__c, pba__Status__c 
             FROM pba__Listing__c WHERE Id != :recordId AND pba__ListingPrice_pb__c > :price - range AND pba__ListingPrice_pb__c < :price + range
         ];
     }
  }
}
```